# Drools matches irrespective of the inserted values in the session

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have a number of rules which use a number of globals. I have created a package called products with multiple files. The structure is like this
  src/main/resources/products
   product.drl
   product-types.drl

In the first file product.drl, I have a number of rules which group a product in specific categories based on attributes of the product. Here is a simple rule which I use to group products based on a category produce

```
  rule "select the vegetable category of produce"
    when $product: Product($code: productCode, $category: category) from products.produceList
    ProductCategory(this.code == $code, this.category == $category)
    then
     insert($product);
     System.out.println ("Matched "+ $product);
end
```

The rule above matches the correct product. However, when I use in the second drl file i.e. product-types.drl, it matches all the products in the list, even though I insert only the match in the i.e. session which matches the specific category which is the vegetable code in ProductCategory.

Here is a rule in product-type.drl

```
rule "Create the summary of product in vegetable category"
 when 
     $matchedProduct: $product: Product($code: productCode, $category: category)
then 
   System.out.println("Matched "+$matchedProduct);
end
```

This does not work, it prints all the Products in the global, products.produceList

I tried using a high salience in product.drl as I thought that the rule in product.drl were being fired before the rule in product-type.drl could see the product matched but that did not help

Comment: Are you sure you are not inserting the products from the global in some other part of your app? Could you create a self-contained reproducer of this problem?

Comment: Yes, that right, I checked and realized that for debugging I had actually done that, thank you for your suggestion. That helped me greatly, once I removed the inserts of the global it worked as expected. Thanks again